# Immersions that are not diffeomorphisms from open sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself

Tags: differential-geometry, diffeomorphism

Let’s say I have an immersion $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$, with $\Omega$ an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is a local diffeomorphism (because its differential is injective and thus bijective), so it is an open map. If I restrict the image and consider it to be not $\mathbb{R}^n$, but $f(\Omega)$, it would also be surjective. The only way it could not be a diffeomorphism is to not be injective, so I was wondering: are there counterexamples? Maybe that work on all dimensions (I don’t see how to give a counterexample in dimension 1, but it might be a special case where there are actually no counterexamples, while in greater dimensions there are)

Comment: Could one not just take an open tubular neighbourhood of a self-intersecting smooth curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$? The only case this wouldn't work in is dimension 1, as you say.

Comment: I haven’t studied open tubular neighborhoods yet (I will very soon, though!)

Comment: By the way, I originally wrote the post confusing the word embedding with immersion, and I have discovered there is no “embedding” tag! Isn’t it a very important topic in differential geometry?

Comment: All I mean is, take an open cylinder around the $x$-axis. Map the $x$-axis to a self-intersecting smooth curve, and then extend that map to the entire cylinder in a smooth way (if you really wanted, you could write a formula, but it's unnecessary).

Comment: I should also mention of course that Rolle's theorem ensures that any smooth non-injective function $\mathbb{R}\supset U \to \mathbb{R}$ for connected open interval $U$ must have a point with zero derivative, so it can't be an immersion.

Comment: Yeah, the thing about Rolle’s theorem is exactly what I thought

Comment: So you take advantage of the fact of being in dimension at least 2 to do this self-intersection without having to have derivative 0. Not sure how to extend things smoothly in the intersection, though. Shouldn’t it give some trouble?

Comment: You could even have a surjective local diffeo from $R^n$ to itself which is not a diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fundamental counterexample which shows up repeatedly as you proceed is the exponential mapping $f\colon \Bbb C\to\Bbb C-\{0\}$, $f(z)=e^z$. (In real coordinates, this is, of course, $f(x,y) = (e^x\cos y,e^x\sin y)$.) Each point has infinitely many preimages, but the map is a *local diffeomorphism* at every point of the domain.